# Incorrect saved datetime to dynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to save datetime as `Date` to dynamoDB but for some reason it is being saved as `string`. I checked on the documentation and `Date` is a supported datatype.
Because of this, when I am trying to `scan` my table, I am getting an error saying `time cannot be unconverted`

```
public class func{
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(func.class);
    private AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    DynamoDBMapper mapper =new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDB);


private boolean addData(MyClass myClass){
        try{
            mapper.save(MyClass);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOGGER.error("error: {}", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }


public List<MyClass> getAll() {
        List<MyClass>  list = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            list = mapper.scan(MyClass.class, new DynamoDBScanExpression());
            return list;
        }catch (Exception ex){
            LOGGER.error("Fetching error: {}", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return list;
    }
}

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "table")
public class MyClass {
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="id")
    public String id;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="create_time")
    public Date createTime;
    public void setCreateTime(Date createTime){ this.createTime = createTime;}
    public Date getCreateTime(){ return this.createTime; }
}
```

OOPS: Sorry. Forgot to read entire document. Seems like Date is of String type https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html

How can I overcome the error when I am trying to scan through the table?

Answer (score 1):

You already linked to the relevant [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html):

| Java type | DynamoDB type |
| --- | --- |
| All number types | N (number type) |
| Strings | S (string type) |
| Boolean | BOOL (Boolean type), 0 or 1. |
| ByteBuffer | B (binary type) |
| Date | S (string type). The Date values are stored as ISO-8601 formatted strings. |
| Set collection types | SS (string set) type, NS (number set) type, or BS (binary set) type. |

Java Dates are mapped to a string type in DynamoDB. This happens for the simple reason that DynamoDB doesn't support Datetime information as a separate datatype.

There's two common ways to encode datetime information in DynamoDB:

- save it as an ISO8601 formatted string, e.g. `2021-02-22T09:58:00.000+01:00`
- save it as a Number in Unix/Epoch format, e.g. `1613984280`

The mapper chooses the former representation, presumably because it's human readable.

Comment: Are you saying to change the datatype in the schema itself to string and then pass string so that the error can be avoided?

Comment: Not a Java programmer myself, but if I interpret the function `FindRepliesInLast15Days` in the [scan/query example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.QueryScanExample.html) correctly, that's what seems to be the suggested solution.